# Headphone-Only Party: Technical Considerations?

Tags: wireless-networking, audio-streaming

I have a robust Macbook Pro and a Netgear RangeMax Wireless-N 150 Router. I plan to have a headphone-only party: I will stream music over Wifi using Airfoil (or something).

Will this setup work? Do I need a better router? What other considerations am I missing, especially in terms of software, hardware, and networking?

For the sake of argument, let's say that there will be 40 smartphones at the party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of having some numbers, I'm going to guess high on everything you are going to see in this example.

Music stream, 256kbps x 40 = 10240 kbps or 10 Mbps

Assume that your wireless N router gives you 100 Mbps

You have 90Mbps for protocol overhead (should be plenty).  However, what about the doofus that decides it's the right time to D/L updates on their smart phone?  And of course everyone is going to be I/Ming and emailing from them.  Then there's the guy that's trying to download the video from YouTube cuz it goes with the song.  That's the type of stuff that will hamstring you.

Comment: I'll remove the uplink. Which is a great point... I'll need to prep the music beforehand with no Pandora! +1

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot: my real question is whether the router will allow that many connections.

Comment: Should be fine.  I'm unaware of any current technology (<3 years old) router/AP that chokes at less than 128 concurrent connections (understand yours COULD be the first ;)

Comment: hmmm... random guy on random thread thinks 25 would be a lot http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=69518

Comment: It appears I'm too used to using high end equipment.  I apologize I may have been wrong.  The question was answered 2 years ago as ~30.  I believe the standard has matured and should support ~40.  You are only really worried about downstream traffic.  Not much upstream should be happening.  http://serverfault.com/questions/105154/how-many-simualtaneous-users-can-wrt54g-handle

Comment: would you mind pointing out some routers that you are "high end," please? Then I could consider cost, etc.

Comment: http://www.overstock.com/Electronics/Cisco-891W-Gigabit-Ethernet-Wireless-Security-Router/4823747/product.html?cid=202290&kid=9553000357392&track=pspla&kw=%7Bkeyword%7D&adtype=pla

Comment: One last thing: there's no reason why I can't hook two cheap routers together via ethernet, right?

Comment: None whatsoever.  I'd set one to be a bridge if you're running DHCP.

Comment: Epic fail. Seems that the computer that was streaming was the weak point, but even at 10 devices the stuttering was unbearable.

Comment: @Yar, thanks for schooling me.  I hadn't anticipated the server would be that much of an issue.

Comment: Going to go with something like Turntable.fm in the future. Though Airfoil works nicely for three or four devices here.